# Finding n keys that all hash to same hash value

Tags: java, random, hash, collision

Hash function given:

```
public int hash4(int k) {
    Random rand = new Random(k);
    return rand.nextInt(size);
}
```

The goal is to find n(size) number of keys(k) that use this hash function to hash to the same hash value (cause collisions). Size is a constant that is passed in by the user and the size will never be greater than 1000. The max value that a key can be is n^2 and you cannot just use the same key over and over. Any help would be appreciated!

My attempt at solving this has been looping from 1 to n using the numbers 1-n as keys, looking for patterns.

Comment: What is `size`? Are you trying to brute force this, or exploit knowledge of how `Random` works?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Size is a constant passed in by the user, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: You can find exactly how Random works online, so I assumed I should use that information to figure it out. Even with that info, I do not see any patterns that would cause all keys to give the same hash value when given a certain size

Comment: You seem to be using `n` as the number of keys that you want to find which hash to the same value. If so what does "if `n` is a power of 2 then all keys hash to the same value" even mean? How does the problem of looking for 4 (rather than say 3) keys magically cause all keys to hash to the same value? Your wording is confusing. In any event, if you want help with homework you should describe your efforts.

Comment: I tested greater powers of 2 and they are close, but do not have the same hash value, so I will take that part out of my question.

Comment: If the max value of a key is n^2, why are you looping from 1-n instead of 1-n^2?  What is the minimum value of a key?

Comment: I need to find n number of keys that hash to the same hash value. However, the value of that key cannot be greater than n^2. So if n == 10, then key cannot have a value greater than 100 and there should be 10 keys total, all hashing to the same hash value

Comment: Yes, but why are you looping 1-n?  It's as if you expect all of the first n numbers to collide, when it could be none of them collide

Comment: So true. That was just my way to check if I could see a pattern. I see no patterns and do not even know where to look anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there are n buckets, with n<sup>2</sup> keys, using the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), we know that one bucket has at least n keys

To figure this out, we're going to need to loop over all the keys

```
int keys = n * n;
for(int i = 0; i < keys; i++)
```

Next we way to see which keys collide is to store each key in a list/set for each group of collisions

```
List<List<Integer>> collisions = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    collisions.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
collisions.get(hash(key)).add(key);
```

Once we have all the collisions, it's simple to look for a list with at least n collisions

```
for(List<Integer> collision : collisions)
    if(collision.size() >= n)
        return collision; //or just print
```

Putting it all together...

```
List<Integer> findCollisions(int n)
{
    List<List<Integer>> collisions = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        collisions.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
    int keys = n * n;

    for(int i = 0; i < keys; i++)
        collisions.get(hash(i)).add(i);

    for(List<Integer> collision : collisions)
        if(collision.size() >= n)
            return collision;
    return null; //this should never happen, due to pigeonholes, but compiler doesn't know
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I do not completely grasp the concept yet, but due to this answer I somewhat understand it now.